# .htaccess manual redirects followed by a general everything else redirect to another domain

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to do a lot of manual redirects followed by a rule which will redirect everything else which isn't covered by the manual redirect.

I have already written a lot of rules following the structure shown below:

```
Redirect 301 /articles/1/1/1.htm http://newdomain.com/relevant-page/relevant-inner-page/
```

I just need to finish this off with a general redirect that will redirect all other pages not covered to the root of the new domain.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. What is 'all other pages'? What is the common format for these pages? Also, have you attempted anything?

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear. All other existing pages on the website that are not being covered by the manual redirects.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I am asking if the remainder of the pages follow a specific format. It would also be good to know where you want the remainder of the pages to redirect to. You will more than likely be using `mod_rewrite` for this, but we can't help until you provide clear information about what you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to do this would be to just PHP redirect in the header of the website. Works for me no problems!